# How to use StatisticsGen with RaggedTensor?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tfx

I am having a problem with the StatisticsGen component of TFX.
I use TFRecords and as input data I use  RaggedTensors (The TFrecord is created with SequenceExample)
After using ExampleGen which splits the file correctly into train and val, StatisticsGen creates a 0kb file and therefore is not working correctly.

Can anyone confirm me that the RaggedTensors are supported by TFX? If so, can you help me generate the statistics?

TF Version:  2.4.1
Eager mode:  True
TFX Version:  0.28.0
TFDV version:  0.28.0
TFT version:  0.28.0
TFMA version:  0.28.0
Hub version:  0.9.0
Beam version:  2.28.0

```
!pip install tfx
import tensorflow as tf
from tfx.components import ImportExampleGen
from tfx.components import SchemaGen
from tfx.components import StatisticsGen
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input
from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2
from tfx.orchestration.experimental.interactive.interactive_context import InteractiveContext
import tfx
import os
import apache_beam as beam
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
import tensorflow_transform as tft
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import logging
path_to_test = os.path.join("tf_records")
context = InteractiveContext(pipeline_root='pipeline_root')

#examplegen
example_gen = ImportExampleGen(input_base=path_to_test)
context.run(example_gen, enable_cache=True)

print(example_gen.outputs['examples'].get()[0].uri)
train_uri = os.path.join(example_gen.outputs['examples'].get()[0].uri, 'train')

tfrecord_filenames = [os.path.join(train_uri, name)
                      for name in os.listdir(train_uri)]

#statisticsgen
statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'])
context.run(statistics_gen)
context.show(statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the creation of the TFRecords, instead of using SequenceExample, we solved the issue using Example. Now the StatisticsGen is working, showing the statistics of the dataset.

Comment: Hey, may I know how did you write Ragged Tensors to TFRecords using tf.train.Example? Thanks